# Send realtime tracking to Contacts via Swift Mapbox

Tags: swift, location, tracking

I am currently sending family members the longitude and latitude via a text message, but I need to replace them with real-time updates on the user's location.

I want to send a URL via a text message of the user's location and when the family member opens it, it will stream the user's location back to the family member for a specified amount of time.

This is what I currently have to send the GPS location to family members:

```
@IBAction func SOS_Pressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let userLoc = map.userLocation!
    
    let userLat = userLoc.coordinate.latitude
    let userLon = userLoc.coordinate.longitude
    
    if
        (MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()) {
        let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
        controller.body = "Help me. My location is: \(userLon) \(userLat)"
        
        controller.recipients = ContactsPHArray    // controller.recipients = [ContactsPhone]
        
        
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self
        self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
    //... handle sms screen actions
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thank you, Legends!

Comment: What is your question?  Youa already had the same question yesterday.  Why don't you edit it?

Comment: I want to be able to stream the users location to a family member when a link is clicked.